# How super().__init__() works when I inherit str class?

Tags: python

I am trying to inherit `str` class for fun.

I provided two ways, 1) using `super()` and 2) using `str` class in the constructor as follows:

```
class Str2(str):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__()  # I did not use `value` here, but my code works!

    def ishello(self):
        if self == "Hello":
            return True
        else:
            False


s = Str2("Hello")
print(s.upper())  # a method of str class
print(s.ishello())  # a new method I defined in Str2 class
```

```
class Str2(str):
    def __init__(self, value):
        str.__init__(value)  # It makes sense for me

    def ishello(self):
        if self == "Hello":
            return True
        else:
            False


s = Str2("Hello")
print(s.upper())  # a method of str class
print(s.ishello())  # a new method I defined in Str2 class
```

I am wondering how `super().__init__()` works in my first code although I did not use `value`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `str` almost certainly uses `__new__` to set the value

Comment: @MadPhysicist it does, I checked! The gist is then that `__new__` expects a value, but `__init__` (super or otherwise) does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str.__init__` does not do anything (similar to `tuple.__init__`, among other immutable classes). The actual initialization happens in `__new__`. Conceptually, this makes sense, since `__new__` returns a new object, while `__init__` can be run multiple times on an existing one. That means that whether you call `super().__init__` or `str.__init__` with or without an argument, or even omit the call entirely, you will get the same result.

When you call `Str2(value)`, you are actually calling `type.__call__(Str2, value)`, which passes `value` to both `__new__` and `__init__`. Since you did not override `__new__`, you get the full benefit of its behavior no matter what `__init__` does.

In short, if you don't want to modify `value`, you can get rid of your custom `__init__`. If you do want to modify `value`, override `__new__` instead:

```
class Str2(str):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        value = "My prefix " + value
        return super().__new__(cls, value)
```